# Are taxonomy fields exposed to views?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I am trying to create a view of nodes that have a taxonomy reference field. I can get the taxonomy term but do not see the taxonomy fields that I've created exposed to views. Google searches do not reveal anyone else having the same issue. Am I missing something right under my nose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Relationships? It's right there in the views edit page. Since you're showing nodes, you are probably going to need to declare you want to show taxonomy term fields.

Comment: oh yes now i see it. I have to create a relationship to the filed in the taxonomy and not the taxonomy itself.