# Structure for a list of links

Tags: 7, entities, taxonomy-terms, nodes, navigation

What I’m looking to do:

- Content type has an field (addable; unlimited entries to this field)
- In that field you select from a list of (mostly external) links.
- Each link is a sentence - has a title and [pre/post text](https://www.drupal.org/node/1485440).

So a piece of content displays a number of formatted links, and these links can be pulled into a view elsewhere.

How could I build that list of links? (content type, field group, taxonomy with link as the name, haven't been able to figure out something that works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One working solution:

- Create a vocabulary where each term has 3 additional fields - a text field, a Link field, and another text field. Add the Term Reference to the content type. Use something like [Chosen](https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen) for selecting ease in needed.
- Use `hook_field_formatter_info()` in a custom module to define a display of the 3 fields as desired. [Unfortunately, displaying term fields on the content/node page doesn't have a quick & easy configurable solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1770/display-taxonomy-field-in-node-display).

Answer (score 0):

Use a taxonomy, separate content type to store rich links. Use entity reference to embed those links in your content and view modes to format the display.

If you want to customize the display further without templates you can use panels.

You can also take a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/panopoly_widgets